# Portable, tool-independent test automation

Tags: testing, language-agnostic, automated-tests

Our codebase contains code in multiple languages, ranging from Python over C# to MATLAB and LaTeX. Currently we have unit tests in each individual language (using language-specific frameworks). This makes test automation cumbersome, especially collecting and checking all the different reports.

I am therefore looking for a test automation tool that

- is portable (at least Windows + Linux)
- is language-independent
- can be extended (custom reporting, additional languages, ...)

Ideally the tool would connect via plugins to the existing tool-specific frameworks like Python's `unittest`, C#'s `NUnit`, etc.

Is there such a tool? If not, how do you handle test scenarios like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like the [Test Anything Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Anything_Protocol)?

> The Test Anything Protocol (TAP) is a protocol to allow communication between unit tests and a test harness. It allows individual tests (TAP producers) to communicate test results to the testing harness in a language-agnostic way.

It doesn't avoid the need for language-specific tests, but it does make sure that your test results are all in a uniform format, so that you can build cross-langauge reports.  It's also fairly simple, so if your language of choice doesn't have a TAP producer, it is not very difficult to write one (and maybe share it back to the world).

Comment: Looks like a start. I don't like the Perl-ish, semi-structured output format, but on the other hand there are already a lot of plugins/producers for different languages. This doesn't cover test discovery and execution automation, though. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 4):

If you go with TAP as already suggested, then a complete test infrastructure around that is [Tapper](http://tapper-testing.org/).

The central server assumes some external Linux tools when you need its automation layer but besides that everything else is language and OS independent. It can receive TAP reports regardless how they were started: manual tests, crontab-driven, or the built-in automation which can set up machines from scratch or start tests via ssh.

See above link for more info, especially have a look at the linked presentations.

Summary:

- TAP as protocol for writing tests
- Tapper for the infrastructure

Comment: Thanks for the additional input, Steffen! I'll look into it.